# Crate type from all interface (key: value) values

Tags: typescript

Assume interface like this (can also be a type if needed):

```
interface Layouts {
  Application: 'Home' | 'About' | 'Contact';
  Registration: 'Email' | 'Password' | 'ResetPassword'
}
```

I want to create a new type `type Screens` that has all values (not keys) from `Layouts` interface i.e. `'Home' | 'Email' | 'About' | 'Password'` etc...

Can this be achieved without needing to duplicate data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `keyof` keyword that will allow you to get the types behind the `Layouts` interface keys.

```
interface Layouts {
  Application: 'Home' | 'About' | 'Contact';
  Registration: 'Email' | 'Password' | 'ResetPassword'
}

type Screens = Layouts[keyof Layouts];
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=6&ssc=39&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDJwJ4HsCuYDOyA3gFDLICCADlQDbAJxjBYgBcyA5ABJYC2ETsgA+XCgCNcYIaM4BhVmETSA3GWQAlCAHNg+MFCYt2XAKJ84wWjK4AFOPnwB3LFAAmNzlvwQw9xy7unCQAviQkYBhUKADKCFAQECCEALxomFL4ANoA1hDYMOnYePgAuipAA)

---

---

[image]